# MySQL Select Row Multiple Times

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query

`SELECT name FROM people WHERE age IN ('34','34')`

There is only one row with column `age` of 34, but I want to return that row 2 times since 34 appears twice in the array.

Any solutions?

Comment: How is the query constructed? Is it from something like PHP where you could change the query?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve that you need to duplicate data? Seems like any front end capable of passing in an array should be smart enough to get a single row back if the same value is passed twice.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes it's php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM people 
JOIN (
  VALUES ROW('34'), ROW('34')
) AS t(age) USING (age);
```

Or make it a rare usage of `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT name FROM people 
NATURAL JOIN (
  VALUES ROW('34'), ROW('34')
) AS t(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` to make the union of two request.
In your case it would be :

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE age = '34'
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM people WHERE age = '34'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_TABLE` to split the values you're looking for into rows, then apply `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
INNER JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         '[34,34]',
         "$[*]"
         COLUMNS(
           Age int PATH "$"
         )
       ) as s on s.age = p.age;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/eZ1LPoo4)